# Question: how to find edges in a picture, using numpy functions

Tags: image, numpy, python-3.7

I want to find the "edges" in a picture. To clarify the term edge, an edge is any pixel where the colour changes more than a certain threshold.

To tackle this, I received some guidelines:

- Find the distance between all neighboring pixels. Find the distance   between all neighboring pixels. First find the difference per colour channel.
- Then combine those to get a single number (use Euclidean)
- Find the pixels where the distance is more than a certain threshold. Those pixels must receive a specific colour, in order to make the edges visible.

I'm not working with python for a very long time, so this is quite a hard job for me. Can anyone help? I was thinking: 
First make a function that calculates the distance between 2 pixels. Like this: `def what_is_distance_between_pixels(image, pixel1, pixel2)`

Then create a function that performs the function above for all pixels. But I'm not sure if this will work.
Something like this (sketch):

```
def distance_between_all_pixels(image, threshold):
    height = image.shape[0] 
    width = image.shape[1]
    colour = image.shape[2]
    for y in range(0,height):
        for x in range(0,width):
            for z in range(0,colour):
                distance = what_is_distance_between_pixels(image, image[y,x,z], image[y+1,x,z])
                if distance > threshold:
                    image[x,y,z] = 0
                distance_2 = what_is_distance_between_pixels(image, image[y,x,z], image[y,x+1,z])
                if distance_2 > threshold:
                    image[x,y,z] = 0
```

Does anyone have an idea on how to tackle this?
I hope I explained my question well.

Comment: Is there any particular reason for not using already existing libraries such as [`opencv`](https://docs.opencv.org/trunk/da/d22/tutorial_py_canny.html) for that task?

Comment: @s.k As I think I can learn more from it when it is build from scratch :)